# EditorTemplate as a dynamic form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, dynamicform

I have a form that will load some fields when the page is requested and some other fields that will be loaded as the user choses one option in a dropdown. The fields that should be loaded upon selection are EditorTemplates. Is there a way I could make it work without the need to refresh the page (i.e a partial view requested via ajax)  and keeping the "binding" to my viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible as long as you respect the naming conventions of your input fields so that the default model binder can understand them. Here's an example of those [conventions for lists](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). And here's a [great article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) illustrating how you could implement editing a variable length list.